# How to convert value of hex String to double in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I have a hexadecimal value saved in a string, that I want to convert it to a double. 
For example, I have `string temp = "08E97091"`, and after conversion the result should be 14.9516433.

Comment: Please, provide the expmple(s): the initial value(s) you've got and the expected outcome(s)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [BitConverter](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.int64bitstodouble) class or you can do something like this :
For eg:

```
byte x = Convert.ToByte(hexValueInString, 16);
double doubleX = Convert.ToDouble(x);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string hexnumber = "00c6";
double doubleValue = (double)Convert.ToInt32(hexnumber, 16);
```

Comment: Add some little bit of information about the resolution taken against the problem to understand better for OP and others as well.